# How do I make Sketch's vector tool only draw on pixel boundaries, not centering them?

Tags: sketch-app

Very annoyingly, I can't seem to get Sketch to draw on pixel boundaries. If I use the vector tool (pressing V) and click two points in a straight line, it centers the 1px line on the pixel boundary, causing 0.5px on each side, and when zoomed in to be a grossly blurred line.

However, if I were to just use the rectangle tool (pressing R) and draw a 1px high box line, that wouldn't be blurred at all and would reside against (not centered on) the pixel boundary as expected.

How do I make Sketch not draw the lines blurry?

Answer (score 2):

The Sketch Documentation on [Pixel Precision](https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/13-other/5-pixel-precision.html) should tell you everything you need to know.

You can change the 'rounding' option to snap to half-pixels, or off completely. And you can always manually edit the position of your points to half-pixel values.

[image]

Comment: But having it set to round to full pixel edges only puts the anchor points on full pixel edges. It's still set to draw from the center, so it'll be drawing 0.5px on either side of the center, which causes the blurring.

Comment: Then set it to round to half pixels?